# opendns works with manual configuration but not via dhcp assigned dns

Tags: windows-10, router, home-networking, vlan, opendns

I have several vlans created. All devices attached to these vlans can access internet with no issue. I am using tomato build 132 on an asus rt-n66u router.

When the windows 10 computer and windows xp computer is configured manually for dns, I can resolve names and no opendns oops! page appears.

But when the computers are set to obtain dns automatically and use router for opendns the "oops!" page appears.

I have the opendns servers, all 3, entered in the tomato dns settings. I tried all of the standard procedures like flush dns cache and clear browser cache.

The opendns support said "From what I can see right now, your router isn't actually able to use OpenDNS servers and send them out on your network. The NSLOOKUPs that you've performed proves this, along with the test you did by applying the OpenDNS servers directly on your computer(s)."

Is there a bug in tomato build 132 with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about how you configured tomato's DNS and DHCP settings?

Comment: @stueja thanks for replying. Each vlan has its own subnet and has its own dhcp server. Below is a link:

Comment: @stueja http://www.snbforums.com/attachments/printscreendnsservers-jpg.6801/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the replies. I found what the trouble was. I was using dnscrypt-proxy. I was using the 4armed resolver under basic:network:resolver. It did not work for opendns. I selected instead the cisco resolver and everything works now. Other resolvers may work I have yet to try them out. Anyhow, the other option to make it work was to not use dnscrypt-proxy. Opendns works fine now but the opendns support was not that helpful. They didn't seem to know the ins and outs of how to make it work. I had to experiment on my own to get things to work. I hope that this info will help out others.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from the screenshot it is not visible, however:

make sure that your tomato will act as a DHCP server. The DHCP server will hand out the DNS servers together with the "usual" stuff like IP addresses and subnet masks.

Go to "Advanced configuration". Check "use internal DNS". Run `ipconfig /renew` on the Win10 box to check.

[image: tomato advanced config]

Comment: each vlan has its own dhcp in tomato. 192.168.10.1/24, 192.168.20.1/24. stp is turned off. tomato lists the wan gateway in the 10.x.x.x range.

Comment: sorry not trying to spam. I'm a newbie here lol. each vlan has its own dhcp in tomato. vlan 10 is 192.168.10.1/24, vlan 20 is 192.168.20.1/24. stp is turned off. tomato lists the wan gateway in the 10.x.x.x range. I tried with intercept 53 on and off. I also tried ipconfig /renew too. I still get the oops! page.